# use AccountManager Authentication in accessing Google Maps

Tags: android, authentication, google-maps

I am trying to use the AccountManager for google login in android , what i want is once the user successfully logged in into the device , i want user to access his custom made map but the problem is i don't know how to make a bridge between AccountManager and MapService ( gdata apis - used to authenticate map service)

I am using following sample code for AccountManager 
[Link to Code](http://alandjackson.wordpress.com/2011/01/05/android-tutorial-snippetsauthenticating-accounts/)

And following is the MapService that is used to authenticate Google Maps

```
MapsService myService = new MapsService("Test");

try {
  // Replace these credentials with your own

  myService.setUserCredentials("userid","password"); 
} catch(AuthenticationException e) {
}
```

i tried to get password using accountManager.getPassword(account) but it was giving me following error even though i have added **android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS**

> java.lang.SecurityException: caller
>   uid 10040 is different than the
>   authenticator's uid